# How do I save SurfaceView's state?

Tags: java, android, multithreading

If it's recreated every time I press button home and then return to the Activity, the thread associated with it will be recreated too.  That implies that the game loop will start at the beginning, so when the user return to the activity, it will be like they just opened the activity.

```
public class GameView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback{
    protected GameThread gameThread; 
    public GameThread(Context context){
        gameThread = new GameThread(this);
        //the rest of the constructor
    }
    //gameview's stuff
}

  //and in the thread...

public class GameThread extends Thread{
    protected GameView gameView; 

    public GameThread(GameView gameView){this.gameView=gameView}
    //gameview's stuff
}
```

And in the Activity's onCreate:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(new GameView(this));
```

Comment: I'm not quite clear as to what you're asking...

Comment: @Makoto I'm looking for a way that, when the activity calls "onPause()", save the current "GameView" and then in "onResume()" restart its state.